# How to include all Rust modules from a given folder in mod.rs file in one line?

Tags: rust

I'm looking for a convenience method to include all the Rust files in a given folder into my mod.rs file automatically.  My folder structure looks like the following:

```
views/
  mod.rs 
  view1.rs
  view2.rs 
  view3.rs
```

Is there something like `pub mod **` which would be equivalent to writing `pub mod view1.rs`, `pub mod view2.rs` and `pub mod view3.rs`?  Just trying to save a little extra time here, since any rs file I put in this folder I want to be included in that module.

Comment: I probably wouldn't bother automating this, but how about adding a shell script like `for mod in view*.rs; do echo "use ${mod%.rs};"; done > mod.rs` to some utils folder? You'd still need to invoke that manually whenever you add or remove a module, but it would keep the Rust code explicit and free of magic.

Comment: My general advice is that unexpected magic is worse than a little bit of code repitition or boilerplate. Keep things simple, and there will be fewer surprises.

Answer (score 2):

There is no build in language feature for implicitly picking up all files in a folder. You could write a procedural macro iterating over directory entries and generating `use viewX` statements, but I would dis-advice invoking that much magic, for a bit of convenience.

On another node. Rust does allow you to declare the module in a `views.rs` file which would be located next to the `views` folder in the hierarchy.

Comment: Another option would be generating the code in `build.rs`, which would have far less overhead than a procedural macro in this case, but I really wouldn't recommend either approach.